# How can I make this program return a result?

Tags: java, return

I have been working on this program.

One of the requirements were the following:
*Write a program that is split in to methods at least one of which returns a result*

It don't have any errors but I need to make it return a result in order for it to work properly. More specifically to add a method that returns a result.

Comment: Hint: change `void CalculateAge()` to `int CalculateAge()` return `age`

Comment: What do you mean? you just change ```public static void CalculateAge()``` to ```public static returnType CalculateAge()``` and add a return statement.

Comment: create a function for heartrate, and one for stretch

Comment: @ControlAltDel what? I think "onlinegamerunibro" just what to get the method to return the age.

Comment: If you want main() to return something use System.exit(int) and pass it a value.

Comment: I undid your edit which removed the code which your question is referring to. Without the code the question gets inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you do it make the method to return something like the age

```
        public static void CalculateAge() {
     
            int age;
            int heartRate;
            int stretch;

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("What is your age? "); 

            age = input.nextInt();
     
            System.out.print("What is your heart rate? "); 

            heartRate = input.nextInt();

            age = heart(age, heartRate);
            
            System.out.print("How far can you stretch? "); 

            stretch = input.nextInt();
     
            age = stretch(age, stretch);

            System.out.println("Your body's age is " + age);

        }  //END of CalculateAge
        public static int heart(int age, int heartRate) {
            if (heartRate <= 62) {
                age -= 5;          // block of code to be executed if condition1 is true
            } else if (62 <= heartRate && heartRate <= 64) {
                age--;            // block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is
                                  // true
            } else if (65 <= heartRate && heartRate <= 70) {
                age++;           // block of code to be executed if the condition1 and condition2 are false and 
                                 // condition3 is true
            } else {
                age += 2;       // block of code to be executed if the condition1 and condition2 and condition3
                                // are false and condition4 is true
            }
            return age;

        }
        public static int stretch(int age, int stretch) {
            if (stretch <= 20) {
                age += 4;      // block of code to be executed if condition1 is true
            } else if (20 <= stretch && stretch <= 32) {
                age++;         // block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is
                               // true
            } else if (33 <= stretch && stretch <= 37) {
                age = age + 0; // block of code to be executed if the condition1 and condition2 are false and
                               // condition3 is true
            } else {
                age = age + 3; // block of code to be executed if the condition1 and condition2 and condition3
                               // are false and condition4 is true
            }
            return age;
        }
```

So all I did was split the `heartRate` calculation into a method and also the `stretch` calculation into a method and out them together.

Comment: @onlinegamerunibro ok, sorry, so you please explain what you're trying to do then? I think kind of doesn't get it... T_T

Comment: Or see the first post(before the edit), does that answer your question?

Comment: I didn't downvote your post. Your post was the answer. Someone else did it.

Comment: I know, you can't... QAQ

Comment: I would suggest not doing methods this way. You pass in the age parameters, then you manipulate the age variable itself and there is no need to return the age as it references the same variable that was passed in. To make the function better assign the value of age to a new int in the function and return that. That way age is not inadvertently changed. (yes you assign age as the return of the function but age already represents the same memory location and it makes the statement useless)

Comment: @DarrenMatthews *and there is no need to return the age as it references the same variable that was passed in* - keep in mind that primitive variables are immutable.

Answer (score -1):

It is best to group common functionality together and abstract away the 'inner workings' of a function. You have a few options you can do.

One such option is to gather all the input at the beginning of the program (age, heart rate and stretch) then give these variables to a function to return the body age, e.g.

```
static int getBodyAge(int age, int heart rate, int stretch) { 
   // calculate body age and return
}
```